# After set()'ing Map, returned object is not a Map

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dictionary, immutable.js, next.js

I'm trying to migrate to immutable.js for my states:

```
class Register extends Component<{}, Map<string, string>> {
    state = Map<string, string>();

    onInputValueChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const newState = this.state.set(name, value);
        this.setState(newState);
    }



   render() {
        ...
        <input onChange={this.onInputValueChange.bind(this)} placeholder="john.doe@example.com" name="email" type="email" />   
   }
}
```

So, whenever I type something for first time, it works fine. But whenever I type the second letter, I get `TypeError: this.state.set is not a function` error. If I do `Map.isMap(this.state)` , it returns True for the first time, but returns False every time after that.

See this reproduced: http://nixiedevelopment.club/register

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not set your whole state to a Map, create an immutable variable in your state instead:

```
class Register extends Component<{}, { data: Map<string, string> }> {
  state = {data: Map<string, string>()};

  onInputValueChange(e) {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      this.setState(({ data }) => ({
        data: data.set(name, value),
      }));
  }
...
}
```

Please check [this](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/wiki/Immutable-as-React-state) wiki page for more information about using Immutable as React state.

Comment: But that defeats the usability of immutable.js, doesn't it?

Comment: Just another question -- can I assign an interface to Map data?

Comment: Sure, check my edited answer. Sorry for forgetting the state interface.